# How to install Realm Object Server on Debian 8.6?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I followed the Ubuntu 16.04 directions, since they use the same package manager as I have, apt-get. The curl and apt-get update commands seemed to have worked nicely. The install command does not work:

```
user@os:/home$ sudo apt-get install realm-object-server-de
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package realm-object-server-de
```

How can I install Realm Object Server on Debian 8.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, we haven't packaged the Realm Object Server for Debian Jessie just yet. We have it listed as something that a lot of people want, so we will definitely address it in the near future.

At the moment, we only support:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- RHEL/CentOS 6
- RHEL/CentOS 7